# Responsive AND fixed

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

It would be awesome if someone could help me or say that it is impossible.

I am working on a website with 3 columns, the first for a picture, the second for the navigation and the third for the content. When the screen is big all three columns take 30% of the space and are side by side. it has a breaking point at 560 px. Then every column takes 100% and one is below the other.

On some pages i have a lot of content and it doesn't look that good when you're scrolling and the navigation is miles away (i know i could use a plugin for a ''up'' button).

I want just the content to move when i scroll up and down. The picture and the navigation should stay.
But the site should still stay responsive.

Here is a picture: http://www.dropviewer.com/v.php?i=5284d8ffbb62e.jpg

Is this possible?

Comment: Study media queries..unless do your project with [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) or  [foundation zurb](http://foundation.zurb.com/) which are mobile first layout frameworks

Comment: So what happens to the first two columns when the view is less than 560 and you scroll the content?